# Generic way to perform CURD operation

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

I am new to the Django framework. I want to create generic controller which can accept body as follows

```
{
    "operation":"select",
    "fields":["user_id","user_name","user_email"],
    "table":"user",
    "where":[        
            {
                "field":"user_id",
                "value":"1234",
                "operator":"=",
                "endwith":null
            }

    ]
}
```

produce a proper SQL query and generate proper JSON output.
there is any way to do this using Django rest framework?

Comment: there is no *built-in way in DRF* to do this.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu is this approach is correct?

Comment: CURD is a food  DRF cant make it :D neither anyting built in exists in Django to perform something like this. But you can do it easily. Parse your request use a mysql driver format the query get the result in a dict and your can serialize it simply passing in in `JsonResponse`

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own API view and do all the logic in it. There is no built-in way to do this.

To your second question - honestly, it seems very strange to me to take a REST framework and do everything that controversy with the REST paradigm. For example - table name and operations supposed to be a particular URL and particular HTTP method in REST.

If you want to do it as in the question, I can suggest looking into GraphQL and corresponding Django packages:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/do-you-need-graphql-with-django/
- https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/

Some basics about REST and how it should be done:

- https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-BpqyOT3a8
- https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest